# Django File Field Truncates request.POST Data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django template which is displaying a file field like so:

```
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ auth_users_ext.user_pic.error }}
      Image Upload: {{ auth_users_ext.user_pic }}
  </div>
```

I've used the necessary enctype="multipart/form-data". The field correctly displays a value being pulled from the database, so I have so far assumed that it is functioning as it's supposed to. The problem I'm having is that wherever I place the field within the template file, the request.POST data is truncated at that point.

So, if I place the field last on the form, I get every field above it. If I place the field at the very top of the form, I get nothing at all.

I can read the POST payload in Chrome and verify that the POST data being passed to the view is complete:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

********
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

********
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="staff_id"

98.0
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_user_id"

1069
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_groups"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_groups"

11
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_groups"

13
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="current_pic"

/media/no_pic.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_pic"; filename="Picture0029.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"

Robert
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

Vila
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

bobvila
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

BobVila@thisoldhouse.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="work_number"

1239111234
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile_number"

1239111234
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mgr_id"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZTdhKmOKbDRAXLAm--
```

Regardless, when I specify request.FILES['user_pic'] in the view, I get nothing.

**UPDATED**

Here is the relevant code from the view:

```
def STAFF(request, uid=None, template='auth_user.html'):
    [ ... ]
    user = request.user
    is_admin = user.groups.filter(name='*** ADMIN_GROUP_NAME ***')

    if uid == None:
        instance = AuthUser()
        ext_instance = AuthUserExt()
    else:
        instance = AuthUser.objects.get(auth_user_id=uid)
        ext_instance = AuthUserExt.objects.get(auth_user_id=uid)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get image request.FILE object
        if request.FILES:
            avatar = request.FILES['user_pic']
            # build destination path for os file handling
            dest_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + request.POST['username'] + '/avatar/'
            # create user/avatar dir if not exist
            if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
                os.makedirs(dest_path)
            # open file handle at the intended destination and write our request.FILE
            if os.path.isfile(dest_path + avatar.name):
                os.remove(dest_path + avatar.name)
            destination = open(dest_path + avatar.name, 'wb+')
            destination.write(avatar.read())
            destination.close()
            # build uri path for database insert
            uri_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + request.POST['username'] + '/avatar/' + avatar.name
        else:
            [ ... ] # lands here, because Django produces no request.FILES
```

Comment: Please show your view code.

Comment: Have you checked that Python Imaging Library (PIL) is installed properly?

Comment: @zubair89: there's no actual file processing going on in the model. the only server-side handling would be moving the uploaded file, but it's not getting that far because Django is failing in generating the `request.POST\FILES` data when it encounters this field. this code worked five months ago when it was first tested, but so many things about the environment have changed since then that i have no way of knowing what the issue might be. the logs give no indication that i can detect, simply showing a 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue ended up being the result of some sort of problem with **Google Chrome**. It was apparently having a problem with something about that file field and was truncating the actual POST data being returned to the server, but was handling things internally sufficient to make me think that all was well when I inspected the debug information. Every other browser worked just fine.